# Mongo DB left join with one to many relationship

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Please I need help with this Mongo DB code.

I have two tables(collections) which are `orders` and `users`. My `orders` table has a referencing field named userId that references the user who made the order. A users can have multiple orders. My `orders` table has these fields: (_id, userId, products[], amount) and few others, while my `users` table has these fields (_id, name, username) and some other fields.

I want to join both tables and retrieve all the fields from the `users` collection, and the sum of the total amount that belongs to each user from the `orders` table.

Here is my code:

```js
const data = await Order.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$userId',
          totalAmount: {$sum : '$amount'}
        },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'users',
          localField: 'userId',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'user_orders',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: '$user_orders',
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 1,
          totalAmount: 1,
        },
      },
    ]);
```

What I am expecting:

```js
[
  {
    _id: id,
    name: name,
    username: username,
    totalAmount: sum of the amout field in `orders` table that has the document "_id"
  },
  {
    _id: id,
    name: name,
    username: username,
    totalAmount: sum of the amout field in `orders` table that has the document "_id"
  },
  ...
]
```

The result I am getting:

```js
[
    {
        "_id": "6582e50ca32d27e9638797aa",
        "totalAmount": 840
    },
    {
        "_id": "65805c533b1ce2ec300cd31f",
        "totalAmount": 2520
    },
    {
        "_id": "63f88bea05cc08d340effa59",
        "totalAmount": 840
    },
    {
        "_id": "6582e28e8ee96b5d6962b269",
        "totalAmount": 840
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation:

```js
const data = await Order.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "totalAmount": {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "name": "$user.name",
      "username": "$user.username",
      "totalAmount": 1
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/05AjBj4Lz-W) for a working example.

**Edit**: If your `Order.userId` is stored as a string you will need to convert it to `ObjectId` in order to do the `$lookup` like so:

```js
const data = await Order.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "totalAmount": {
        $sum: "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      userId: {
        $toObjectId: "$_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "userId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "name": "$user.name",
      "username": "$user.username",
      "totalAmount": 1
    }
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Y3c2Jhx612b) for a working example.

**Note**: it is advisable to store the `userId` as an `ObjectId` in the document but if you cannot modify then this is a suitable workaround.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it but it returns an empty array

Comment: @MarvWeb can you paste some documents into your question. One from Orders and one from Users. There is probably a mismatch in document properties somewhere. Have a look at the working example link I provided. Do your documents look similar?  Is the `userId` property an `ObjectId` or string?

Comment: Mine is a string. Please how did you insert `userId` as an `ObjectId` in the `orders` collection

Comment: @MarvWeb can you put them into your question, not into this answer.

Comment: @MarvWeb I have added another example to help you with a work around.

Comment: It's working now. Thanks a lot. How do I store the `userId` as an `ObjectId`

Comment: @MarvWeb see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251251/21972629) for how to store the `ObjectId` from one document into another document from two different collections.